# fill database table in wxListCtrl using wxThread- i can fill but system is going to hang

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Firstly i make a program for showing table in wxListCtrl, it worked but for limited amount of data..
it shows a problem like:-
when i execute the program . frame do the visible after some time... but it works
 then i turns to use wxThread now everthing is going fine, now when i execute the program frame immediately visible because i write Sleep(1000), so it add a line in wxListCtrl one by one , but it is giving unexpected result depend upon how many rows are in database..
my code is:-

```
# include "thread.h"
# include "login.h"
# include "sql.h"
# include <mysql.h>

class List_Ctrl_Data;

MyThread :: MyThread(login* login_obj)
{
     this->temp = login_obj;
}
void *MyThread :: Entry()
{
    int i=1,j,k=0   ;
    while(i!=100)
    {
            long index=this->temp->data_list_control->InsertItem(i,wxT("amit"));
            for(j=1;j<3;j++)
            {
               this->temp->data_list_control->SetItem(index,j,wxT("pathak"));
            }
            k++;
            if(k==1)
            {
                            k=10;
                       this->Sleep(1000);
            }
            i++;                                                
    }
}
```

here data_list_control is the object of wxListCtrl , with the help of thread i m filling value inside the wxListCtrl.
some people advised me that here u r knocking frame control( wxListCtrl) again and again from thread entry , 
thats why frame getting hanged you should use wxPost or AddPendingRequest for this, i dont think that it would work, 
i tried to explain you my prob, still u feel to ask anything , u r welcome.. if you will help me, it would be a lot for me

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992690/how-to-display-large-data-in-wxlistctrl-with-using-concept-of-wxthread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*****************************************************SOLUTION IS HERE***********************************

i used the code in thread like[ it get a row from database and pass to event]
void *MyThread :: Entry()

```
{

    List_Ctrl_Data obj1 ;
    MYSQL_RES *database_table_data;
    database_table_data=obj1.getdata();
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    while((row=mysql_fetch_row(database_table_data))!=NULL)
        {

            wxCommandEvent event( wxEVT_COMMAND_TEXT_UPDATED, 100000 );
            void *row_data;
            row_data=(void *)row;
            event.SetClientData(row_data);
            temp->GetEventHandler()->AddPendingEvent( event );
            this->Sleep(1000);

        }


}
```

and for handling this we create a event table and a function to handle this value-
    void onNumberUpdate(wxCommandEvent& evt);
        private:
    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
in header file and in cpp file we write

void login::onNumberUpdate(wxCommandEvent& evt)

```
{

    int i=0,j;

    void* hold_row;

    hold_row=(void *)evt.GetClientData();

    MYSQL_ROW row;

    row=(MYSQL_ROW)hold_row;

    //while(row!=NULL)

    //{

        //wxPuts(wxT("kjhjkh"));

        const char* chars1 = row[0];

        wxString mystring1(chars1, wxConvUTF8);

        long index=data_list_control->InsertItem(this->counter,mystring1);
    this->counter++;

        for(j=1;j<3;j++)

            {

            const char* chars2=row[j];

            wxString mystring2(chars2,wxConvUTF8);

            data_list_control->SetItem(index,j,mystring2);
            }

    //}

}
```

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(login, wxFrame)
EVT_COMMAND  (100000, wxEVT_COMMAND_TEXT_UPDATED, login::onNumberUpdate)

END_EVENT_TABLE()

and finally i got the solution of my problem//////

www.rohitworld.site90.net OR ROHITAMITPATHAK@GMAIL.COM

Comment: I guess this works, although, note that generating and posting an event for every row in your database table is a huge performance hit. This could be optimized significantly.

Comment: Additionally, while using wxEVT_COMMAND_TEXT_UPDATED doesn't harm anything here, it's generally not recommended to re-use existing built-in event types for completely different purposes like this. It's not hard to define your own custom event type.

Answer (score 1):

The problems you are seeing are likely due to the fact that you are calling methods on a GUI control from a secondary thread rather than the main thread. This should *never* be done. You need to add the items from the main thread.

I'm guessing one of the reasons you have attempted to do this from a secondary thread is because it takes too long to add large number of items, and it's hanging your user interface. The correct approach is either to use a virtual list control (as noted in the "duplicate" question @Erik mentioned), or to periodically call wxYield (or wxSafeYield) while adding items so that UI events are processed.